# Selecting only rows that return a matching column value using CASE THEN

Tags: sql, select, case

I have the following SQL query and I am trying to return only invoices where the MAKE is set set to 'BANER', this is getting all rows of the invoice table with all the BANER rows at the bottom, how can I return the rows only where BANER is the make?

```
SELECT [ART_NO],
       [QTY],
       [DUE_DATE],
       make=CASE make
              WHEN 'BANER' THEN 'BANER'
              ELSE ' ' + make
            END,
       [PRODUCT],[PRICE],[DETAIL],
       [COLOUR],[RS1],[RS2],[RS3],
       [RS4],[RS5],[RS6],[RS7],[RS8],
       [RS9],[RS10],[RS11],[RS12]
FROM   [DBKular].[dbo].[INVOISTK]
WHERE  make != ''
ORDER  BY [MAKE] ASC,
          [DUE_Date]
```

Comment: You could get answers a lot faster if you would remove everything from your query that is not related to the question and format it properly to avoid scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need `case statement` in your query just a `Where clause` is what needed. After filtering `Make = 'Baner'` there won't be any other make's.

```
SELECT [ART_NO],
       [QTY],
       [DUE_DATE],
       [make],
       [PRODUCT],[PRICE],[DETAIL],
       [COLOUR],[RS1],[RS2],[RS3],
       [RS4],[RS5],[RS6],[RS7],[RS8],
       [RS9],[RS10],[RS11],[RS12]
FROM   [DBKular].[dbo].[INVOISTK]
WHERE  make = 'BANER'
ORDER  BY [MAKE] ASC,
          [DUE_Date]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way to filter rows for a specific value would be to *use the clause designed to filter rows for a specific value* - [the WHERE clause!](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

```
SELECT 
    [ART_NO],
    [QTY],
    [DUE_DATE],
    make=
        CASE make 
            WHEN 'BANER' 
            THEN 'BANER' 
            ELSE ' ' + make 
        END, 
    [PRODUCT],
    [PRICE],
    [DETAIL],
    [COLOUR],
    [RS1],
    [RS2],
    [RS3],
    [RS4],
    [RS5],
    [RS6],
    [RS7],
    [RS8],
    [RS9],
    [RS10],
    [RS11],
    [RS12] 
FROM 
    [DBKular].[dbo].[INVOISTK] 
WHERE make = 'BANER' 
ORDER BY 
    [MAKE] asc, 
    [DUE_Date]
```